# MongoDB using $text with other query params

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to search for topic, name, and keywords. I expect to search first for the text and if find posts with those words in it to find the user and then to query by user.name and the topic, but when I use this:

```
const posts = await Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $text: {
            $search: postWords ? `${postWords}` : /.*/,
            $caseSensitive: false,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "user",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$user",
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            {
              topic: {
                $regex: postTopic ? postTopic : /.*/,
                $options: "i",
                $exists: true,
              },
            },
            {
              "user.name": {
                $regex: postName ? postName : /.*/,
                $options: "i",
                $exists: true,
              },
            },
            { text: { $regex: postWords ? postWords : /.*/, $options: "i" } },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $skip: req.params.page ? (req.params.page - 1) * 10 : 0,
      },
      {
        $limit: 11,
      },
      {
        $project: {
          "user.password": 0,
          "user.active": 0,
          "user.email": 0,
          "user.temporaryToken": 0,
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Let's say the text is lorem ipsum and I try to search for with keywords like "ipsum lorem" doesn't work, but with "lorem ipsum" works. postWords is a string with words separated with white space (I can make it array as well if it is needed).

EDIT 1:

```
$and: [
            {
              topic: {
                $regex: postTopic ? postTopic : /.*/,
                $options: "i",
                $exists: true,
              },
            },
            {
              text: {
                $regex: `/${postWords}/g`,
                $options: "i",
              },
            },
            {
              "user.name": {
                $regex: postName ? postName : /.*/,
                $options: "i",
                $exists: true,
              },
            },
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to search by keywords. Let me give you an example if we have following text in post N "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" if I have the following keywords "ipsum sit" or "ipsum Lorem" to return this post.

Comment: $text takes a string argument, not a regular expression. Have you tried examples in documentation for $text?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. That's why place question here. Any ideas where can be the problem?

Comment: How was the text index created?

Comment: I added this to the schema `PostSchema.index({ $text: "text" });`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this part

```
{ text: { $regex: postWords ? postWords : /.*/, $options: "i" } }
```

It can be visualized as

```
{ text: { $regex: /lorem ipsum/i } }
```

in the case where it matches and gives the output is because you are matching exact `lorem ipsum` with the text `lorem ipsum` in your document so it matches.
You can see the example [here](https://regex101.com/r/C1u6b0/1)

---

But when you specify `ipsum lorem` query becomes this

```
{ text: { $regex: /ipsum lorem/i } }
```

and you can clearly see that this regex doesn't match the text `lorem ipsum` in your document. You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/vnmDi5/1)

So what we need to do now is construct a regex that matches your text lorem ipsum in both cases

```
/lorem|ipsum/gmi
```

`|` matches either ***lorem*** or ***ipsum***

You can see the working [here](https://regex101.com/r/m0yZAp/1)

Comment: Awesome answer! that's what I was looking for.Btw I was thinking about the same, but wasn't sure about what was happening exactly. So how you think exactly should be. Something like `{ text: { $regex: /\`${postWords}\`/gmi } }` ? and also it give me the following error `Missing expected field "$search"`

Comment: you need to replace `space` with `|`, you can use something like `/${postWords.replace(" ", "|")}/gmi`

Comment: I allready handle this! thanks, but still give this error `Missing expected field "$search"`

Comment: `$match: {$text: {$search: postWords,$caseSensitive: false,},}` I'm using this one and now only problem is that return only if first words is there. Example : if I have in the DB following text "hello my friend" it will work with "my|hello" and "hello|friend", but when I try to remove first word returns nothing.

Comment: with `$search`, you have to provide space-separated string like `"hello friend"` and with `$regex` you have to use pipe in between words like `/hello|friend/`

Comment: Yes, but when i try to use `$search` shows only if first word exists `hello friend` it will work, but if I type `friend hello` doesn't work, dunno why :/ .

Comment: what are you passing to $search and what are you passing to $regex ?

Comment: I'm passing `hello friend` to `$search` and `hello|friend` to regex

Comment: Any ideas what to try?

Comment: what exactly your text field contains and what are you passing, please write that in a neat way

Comment: I have building advanced search and searching posts with following fields: topic, user.name and text is not working properly. I want to search all not blank fields (aka empty string), but finds the post only if first words is matching ( Doesn't look all words in text, but only first one. I think im doing it wrong with regex, so I need some help there) Let me know if you doesn't understand something I will explain more